# extracting subset of iteration in jags.samples() in r

Tags: r, markov-chain-montecarlo, jags, coda

Using rjags and jags.samples (), I have multiple parameters that are monitored and some parameters are in matrices. This means for example, with 2 chains and 5000 iterations, jags.samples() may return a list of mcarrays, say, "samp":
par1 has dimension [1:2,1:2,1:5000,1:2]
par2 has dimension [1:2,1:10,1:5000,1:2]
par3 has dimension [1,1:5000,1:2]

How can I extract say just selected iterations, e.g. siters=c(1:100,1000:1100), in one step without having to do this for each individual parameter?